# Creating a report that will display a number of images from filenames in a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a VBScript that I use to read an XML file and populate a couple of tables in Access 2010. The VBScript also copies jpg files from a card reader to a location on the server. The VBScript creates a unique folder based on date/time...the folder location of each image name is written to the database as one of the fields in `UNC path\filename.jpg` notation.

I have a primary database and the transaction (images) are referenced in the second database. I have created a relationship as well...
I am able to build my report in Access from data from both the tables, however, I'd like to automate a print job that grabs the last entry to the primary database, it's associated images (up to 10...but not 10 in every case) and print them out. When I try to build the report I cannot figure out how to use a query result of the field with the filenames to display on the report.

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: I didn't know what to try...but, Gord nailed it below! Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you describe using an `Image` control and a line of VBA code. For a sample table named [ImageLocations]

```
ImageLocation                           
-----------------------------------
\\SERVER\Public\Pictures\image1.jpg        
\\SERVER\Public\Pictures\image2.jpg
```

I created a report with that table as the `Record Source`, dropped the [ImageLocation] field onto the Detail band, and added an `Image` control. I used the following as the `On Format` event of the report's Detail section:

```vbs
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.ImageControl.Picture = Me.ImageLocation.Value
End Sub
```

When I print the report I see the images associated with the filenames in the table.

### Edit re: comment

Newer versions of Access (since at least Access 2010) do not need the `On Format` VBA code. We can simply place an `Image` control on the report and set its `Control Source` property to the (text) field containing the path to the image file. Thanks to Albert D. Kallal for the tip!

Comment: Didn't see this but, yes you are correct! Thanks for your help!

Comment: from 2010 onwards, you should not even need any code - reports and continues forms can display a image based on a column that has a path to a file. In fact 2007 may have this feature, but for sure 2010 and 2013 does and it works without any code required at all

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks Albert! I will update my answer.