# Displaying Images from a Folder in an Access Report is very slow

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a report in Access which displays an image (along with other additional information) from a path stored in a table. I found a [solution](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B285820) provided by Microsoft which worked fine when I had originally tested this with ~25 records. I'm now trying to run this with almost 600 records (which ends up being around 55 pages) and it doesn't seem to be working. When I print preview, each page will load **very** slowly. When I attempt to print to a PDF it does not work. I can see the dialog box saying "Printing Page x of n" but it doesn't seem to complete the process. I'm wondering if anyone has used a different suggestion of how to do this or how to tweak the solution above to work a little more efficiently.

Comment: Since you are using Access 2010 perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20893834/2144390) might help.

Comment: @GordThompson Sorry for the late response. Thank you for showing me that! It sure does make things more simple and a bit more responsive. Not that this is a true "solution", but I am able to print my report to a PDF as long as I don't touch the mouse while the dialog box stating "Print nn out of xx pages" is displayed.