# Some images do not display on Access Report though image url is valid

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a report in access 2010 with an image that is controlled by a text field in a table that stores the image URL (thanks to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892445/creating-a-report-that-will-display-a-number-of-images-from-filenames-in-a-table)). The report has about 500 records (each with it's own corresponding image) and ends up being about 50 pages long. I am having an odd situation where an image will not display even though the image URL is valid. At this point it does not seem to have a pattern. I tried checking the image sizes (which are around 1 MB - 3 MB), but there does not seem to be a pattern there. Has anyone had this situation before that might be able to shed some light?

Comment: If you repeat it, is it always the same image or is it a random image?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes When I repeat it, I will get different images. There are some images that never have issues, but some that will show one time but not another.